# QWAT installation on Windows

Tags: qgis, installation

I'm trying to install [QWAT](https://qwat.github.io/docs/master/en/html/) but when I get to the step where I have to create the `pg_service.conf` file I get confused I don't where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an environment variable called `PGSYSCONFDIR` pointing to the location you wish to store the `pg_services.conf` file. Then you just put that file in the location `PGSYSCONFDIR` points to. Remember to save it as a UNIX Format using Notpad++ or something similar.

Comment: Please edit your answer to revise it rather than adding a comment as an addendum to it.